# How do I handle this Nested JSON in PHP as below?

Tags: php

I've a GET request in PHP that receives data in JSON as below.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1cc58ad2-ccfd-4ede-a6a6-35809c81cb8a",
        "type": "payment",
        "attributes": {
            "status": "Sent",
            "created_at": "2022-05-02T08:57:50.171+03:00",
            "amount": {
                "currency": "KES",
                "value": "500.0"
            },
            "transfer_batches": [{
                "status": "Sent",
                "amount": "500.0",
                "disbursements": [{
                    "amount": "500.0",
                    "status": "Transferred",
                    "origination_time": "2022-05-02T08:57:50.171+03:00",
                    "transaction_reference": "1651471070",
                    "destination_type": "till",
                    "destination_reference": "3eccf0c1-ab6b-41a4-b51a-4e8f588105f1"
                }]
            }],
            "metadata": {
                "something": "TST-01",
                "something_else": "Something else"
            },
            "_links": {
                "callback_url": "http://portal.zarafu.com/payments",
                "self": "https://sandbox.kopokopo.com/api/v1/payments/1cc58ad2-ccfd-4ede-a6a6-35809c81cb8a"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I filter the `transaction_reference` and `status`.
I have tried..

```
    $jsonData = json_decode($response);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $jsonData->status;
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: `var_dump($jsonData->data->attributes->status);` --> "Sent"

Comment: Follow the structure of the data. Clearly, status is not at the top level

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the status like that. You have to use the format of your json. Exemple for the status :

```
echo $jsonData->data->attributes->status;
```

For transaction reference, it's :

```
echo $jsonData->data->attributes->transfer_batches->0->disbursements->0->transaction_reference;
```

I put '0' because it's arrays

Comment: You do not address arrays like that

Comment: @svgta This echo $jsonData->data->attributes->transfer_batches->0->disbursements->0->transaction_reference; does'nt work out.